# How to terminate with Signal with MPI

Tags: c, mpi

This is my first program I wrote with MPI in c, The program is supposed to terminate within 15 secs, but it did not. it did not even go through the if(end_now == 1) statement. Does anyone know what had happened here? The code is simplified as below:

```
int end_now = 0;


void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGUSR1) {
        end_now = 1;
        printf ( "  %8d  %8d\n", current_number, current_total);
    }
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv ){
   int id;
   int count;

   MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &count);
   MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

   signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler);


   while (1){
       //MPI_Allreduce is called here to sum up the subtotal calculated by child processes
        if (end_now == 1){
            printf("here\n");  //this "here is never printed out"
            break;
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize ();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using timeout --signal=USR1 15 mpirun.openmpi -np 2 ./a.out to execute the code on my Mac.
Thanks to whoever may help.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending a signal to `mpirun`, not your executable. Since `mpirun` itself doesn't have a `SIGUSR1` handler, nothing happens.

BTW, using signals with MPI programs is not something you want to do. MPI programs rely on multiple invocations running in lockstep, which doesn't match the asynchronous and per-process nature of signals.

Comment: Thank you for your help. what if i change it to timeout --signal=USR1 15 mpirun.openmpi -np 2 ./a.out? I heard that openMPI supports signal really well.

Answer (score 1):

Sneftel is right. Gilles Gouaillardet is also VERY right. I want to add some other info.

Even if you send the signal to actual program and not to "mpirun", then you possibly send it to ONE only of your processes and not to all of them.

Yes, signals are not right thing to do in MPI programs. But even if you want to use them, you should first debug whatever processes get them and who of them get them.

<s>Insert "printf" directly into signal handler. Print something like "MPI process number %d got the signal" and insert MPI_COMM_RANK into this printf.</s> (UPD 2018-04-27 7:31 MSK: sorry, I didn't noticed you already have such `printf` in your code.) (Note: I think "printf" in MPI programs allowed in first process only, and using "printf" in other processes is probably bad idea, but for debugging purposes will go. Also, I think "printf" directly from signal handler is bad idea, but, again, for debugging purposes will go.)

You will determine if your processes get the signal and which of them.

If you don't satisfied with results, then try different programs instead of gtimeout. For example, "timeout" from GNU Coreutils. (Well, this is Mac, I'm not sure, GNU Coreutils is available form Mac, but I still think you can find SOME "timeout".)

Then: you didn't describe your setup in question. Does your MPI programs run on different hosts or on one? Does MPI "programs" really implemented as separate programs or as threads? Which MPI implementation you use and which version? If you don't know how MPI starts your processes, at least say us, how you installed your MPI implementation and how you configured it.

Or even you can do without any "timeout" or "gtimeout" at all. Just type this in one console:

```
sh -c 'echo $$ > ~/pid-of-mpirun; exec ~/opt/usr/local/bin/mpirun -np 2 ./a.out'
```

This will run "mpirun" while storing its PID into ~/pid-of-mpirun. And run in parallel in another terminal (of course, you don't need to run this command exactly in the same moment):

```
sleep 15; kill -USR1 $(cat ~/pid-of-mpirun)
```

This will want 15 secs and send USR1 to process which PID is in ~/pid-of-mpirun .

But all this will probably send USR1 to "mpirun" and not to actual processes (I am not sure, test this!). How to send to actual processes? Well, you can read manual page for "kill" and try to understand how to send a signal to whole process group and not to just one process.

Also, you can write your PID into some file directly inside your C program.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> // Mac is one of UNIX systems, so we have unistd.h
// ...
FILE *fout = fopen("~/my-pid", "w"); fprintf(fout, "%d\n", getpid); fclose(fout);
```

Of course, you should somehow make sure you create different files in different processes. For example, generate file names from MPI_COMM_RANK.

Comment: Yes my MPI program run on one host, I am trying to actually use this to find prime numbers, and I'm using openMPI to implement this. Sorry I'm still a little confused. Is there any chance that you can show me some modifications on my code? Thanks again

Comment: @AllenLiiu574. I gave you some variants. Explore them, I will not do this for you. I didn't noticed at first that your signal handler already has `printf` I am speaking about. Sorry. So, what is output of this `printf`? Include the output into your question. What processes get the signal? Then try other advice given by me and other people in this question

Comment: @AllenLiiu574. I will say this again: MPI is working badly with signals. So this is first and foremost advice I give to you. If you want your processes to communicate somehow (in particular to get one process to notify about something another process), then use standard MPI methods of communication

Comment: @AllenLiiu574. If you for some reason simply wants all your processes to die after 15 seconds, simply try this: `timeout --signal=KILL 15 mpirun -np 2 ./a.out` or, alternatively, run your processes and type in another console: `sleep 15; killall ./a.out` (Linux typically has `killall`, I am not sure about Mac).

If you want to wait 15 secs and then somehow notify processes about this, try to use standard MPI solution for this. For example, make one of your processes "waiter". Let it sleep 15 secs. And then let it notify other processes (using standard MPI methods) that 15 secs passed

Answer (score 0):

`end_now` should also be declared as `volatile` otherwise the compiler might optimize the main loop that will run forever.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend to not use printf in signal handlers as printf is not reentable function and this can lead to program crash on some platforms.